# Generating random number based on random samples

Tags: random-variable, random-generation, distributions

I have a bunch of samples ~500 from a continuous distribution. The objective is to generate new random samples from this distribution. How to approach this problem? Can someone give me a pointer. I am using Python so I got numpy etc.

Comment: You can look for the term bootstrap and see how/if it is implemented in your favorite software.

Comment: Should the generated numbers be different from the original ones?

Comment: yes, number can be anything in that range. Thanks for the link to the other post :)

Comment: Shimano -- does that one answer your question, or are you looking for something different?

Comment: As stated, i.e., only provided with 500 real numbers, there is no way you can generate new samples from that distribution. Only approximations are available.

Comment: Thanks for your tips guys. The link to the other post is good.